# Remove duplicated files in linux fs with ending e+$

Tags: bash, filesystems, duplicates

I have big filesystem structure which contains many files with different extensions, for example

```
index.html
logo.png
package.zip
```

Many of those files has its duplicates with added `e` letter at the end, so:

```
index.htmle
index.htmlee
package.zipe
```

and so on.

I have to remove recursively every duplicated file with `e+$` at the end. But if there is file

```
file.exe
```

it should remove

```
file.exee
file.exeee
```

but not

```
file.exe
```

What is the best way to remove those files ?

Comment: are extensions known e.g. (only exe,png,zip,txt....) or it could anything?

Comment: Unfortunately it can be anything.

Comment: OK, if it can be anything, how can you tell `ee.e` and `ee.ee` and `ee.eee` are three different files or all dups of `ee.e`? or `ee.e` and `ee.ee` are different files, `ee.eee` is dups of `ee.ee`?

Comment: even interesting, if you have `file.ex` and `file.exe` ....

Comment: There will be always `original` file for duplicates, so it there is `file.zipe` there will be `file.zip`; if there is `file.exee`, original is `file.exe`. If we have `file.exe` and there is no `file.ex`, then `file.exe` is original without duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first I assume you have a list of all files in your directory. It could be a plain text file. let's call it `list`

then this one-liner will do the job:

```
sort list|awk '{if(p&&$0~p"e+$")print "rm "$0;p=$0}'
```

this line above will print `rm foo` commands, `foo` are duplicated files. let's take an example:

```
kent$  cat list
index.html
logo.png
logo.pnge
package.zip
index.htmle
index.htmlee
package.zipe
file.exe
file.exee
file.exeee

kent$  sort list|awk '{if(p&&$0~p"e+$")print "rm "$0;p=$0}' 
rm file.exee
rm file.exeee
rm index.htmle
rm index.htmlee
rm logo.pnge
rm package.zipe
```

you can see, all duplicated files are in generated `rm command`. if you want to execute, just pipe the line to `|sh` so:

```
sort list|awk '{if(p&&$0~p"e+$")print "rm "$0;p=$0}'|sh
```

**EDIT**

it is good practice to wrap the filename with quotes, because filename could have spaces and other special characters:

```
sort list|awk '{if(p&&$0~p"e+$")print "rm \""$0"\"";p=$0}'
```

Comment: It works like a charm. I like the way you print files to remove before executing `rm`, it will allow me to check the list. You're great man !

Comment: forget mentioning, in the `list`, pls don't contain any empty lines. it could be checked, but I didn't do it in this answer.

Comment: Sure thing. I have alredy did my list with `find . > list` so it gives me save result.

Comment: `wc -l list; 167913 list` and `wc -l rmlist; 84586 rmlist` :-)

Comment: Ooops - if filename contains whitespace or `&`, it crases :(

Comment: @hsz oh, yes, can you chk this, if it works: `sort list|awk '{if(p&&$0~p"e+$")print "rm \""$0"\"";p=$0}'`

Comment: Version with `"..."` works well. Update your answer please. Thanks again !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28872/discussion-between-hsz-and-kent)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all files that end in "e"

```
find ./ -name "*e"
```

Then need to reverse sort to name longer names come first

```
| sort -r
```

Then remove the "e"

```
    chk4File=`echo $FILE | sed -e 's/e$//g'`
```

And then compare to make sure it exists prior to removing file with 'e' at the end

```
    if [ "${FILE}" != "${chk4File}" ] && [ -e ${chk4File} ]; then
```

Put it all together...  the example will not remove any files... just tell you which ones will be removed or not...  I suggest doing a test run without deleting any files and review the results prior to a real removal.  Just remove the # in from of the rm command for it to be live.

```
#!/bin/sh
for FILE in `find ./ -name "*e" | sort -r`
do
    chk4File=`echo $FILE | sed -e 's/e$//g'`
    if [ "${FILE}" != "${chk4File}" ] && [ -e ${chk4File} ]; then
        echo "Removing ${FILE} since ${chk4File} was found.."
        #rm -rf ${FILE}
    else
        echo "NOT Removing ${FILE} since ${chk4File} was NOT found.."
    fi
```